# Understand following cases... when fstream opens file and when it doesn't

Tags: c++, fstream

Here is my piece of code:

```
fstream f;
f.open("memory.txt", ios::out|ios::in);//'memory.txt' already exists - I open it

//...(here are some operations performed on file f)...

f.close();
remove("memory.txt");

//             *** Next, I create a file with the same name ***

fstream f1("memory.txt");
f1.open("memory.txt", ios::in |ios::out |ios::trunc);//#

//...(some operations performed on file f1)...

f1.close();
```

---

My questions are:

1. If I replace *#* - line with `f1.open("memory.txt", ios::in |ios::out );`
   the file *f1* won't open. Why ?
2. If I replace *#* - line with `f1.open("memory.txt", ios::in |ios::trunc );`
   the file *f1* won't open. Why ?
3. If I replace *#* - line with `f1.open("memory.txt", ios::out |ios::trunc );` the file will open! Why ?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_filebuf/open

Comment: One question per question please, and a bit of research wouldn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't check if the file has been successfully deleted, it'll fail if the file doesn't exists.
2. `ios::out` has to be set [ref.](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/)
3. `ios::trunc` flag deletes all content if the file does exist, so it'll open whether the file exists or not.

Comment: You mean, for number 1, using in|out will fail if the file _doesn't_ exist.